# Is there a difference in energy required to make 2 items with the same exact mass but different material travel the same distance whilst in free fall?

Tags: gravity, drag, equivalence-principle, free-fall

is there a difference in energy required to make 2 items with the same exact mass but different material travel the same distance whilst in free fall?

Please answer for all cases of free fall: Newtonian Mechanics with/without air resistance & General relativity.

Comment: Comment about terminology: A fall with air resistance is by definition not a free fall.

Comment: @Qmechanic  1/3 answered.  Thank you.  I googled free fall and visited Wikipedia.  Those three cases were mentioned and thought to cover them all :D